# JSS Vue page transitions not fully working in example project

Tags: jss

It seems like the router setup for the JSS Vue example may be preventing the transitions that are built into Vue Router from properly running.  Specifically I am having issues with the leave animation.  It seems like it either gets skips or the enter state runs too quickly.  The enter animation works fine and I have also used this before on more simple Vue app builds.

This is the code I added to `AppRoot.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="app-root">
    <context-view :visible="contextViewVisible" />
    <!-- 'router-view' is a "global" component that is injected into the Vue component registry by vue-router. -->
    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <router-view v-if="!languageIsChanging" />
    </transition>

    <div v-if="languageIsChanging" class="alert alert-info">Language is changing...</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

As well as the CSS for the transition animations:

```
  .slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition-delay: 2s;
  }
  .slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
  }
  .slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
  /* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
    transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

My guess is that it has something to do with how the dynamic routes are being fetched and the logic in  `RouteHandler.vue`.  I'm wondering if there are any other more simple examples of route handling that only deal with fetching the right components and mounting them with the data from SiteCore (no language switcher and graphQL stuff).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're encountering is due to the loading state transitions within the `RouteHandler` component that is rendered by the `<router-view />`. In the code you've provided, the `<transition>` gets applied to whatever is rendered by the `<router-view />` component (which is ultimately the `RouteHandler` component in the sample apps).

However, because route data retrieval is asynchronous, the `RouteHandler` will enter the `loading` state and render a `<route-loading />` component while route data is being retrieved. After route data has been retrieved, the `RouteHandler` will render the `<layout />` component. The `<router-view />` component is therefore technically "swapping" separate components and the `<transition>` that wraps `<router-view />` is trying to apply the transition to *each* component that `<router-view />` renders.

All of that said, it seems like the most straightforward solution might be to move the `<transition />` into the `RouteHandler` component, directly wrapping the components declared in its template. Then also use the transition `mode` property on the `<transition />` component, which is explained in the Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes

For example:

```
<transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
  <not-found v-if="notFound" :context="appState.sitecoreContext" />
  <route-loading v-else-if="loading"  />
  <layout v-else :route="appState.routeData" />
</transition>
```

I also adjusted the css a bit, just to remove the `transition-delay`:

```
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
  /* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(30px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The transition should then behave like:

> Current element transitions out first, then when complete, the new element transitions in.

You may need to experiment with transition timings and delays to achieve your desired effect, but I believe this is the path you'll need to explore.

Alternatively, you may wish to replace the `<route-loading />` component in the sample app with your own transition / loading indicator.

Comment: Yep, exactly the conclusion I have come to.  I tried the mode option but no luck with that either.  The best solution I have is adding custom events that fire my animations and then call `this.$router.push(newRoute)` after a `setTimeout` delay for how long the animation lasts.  This does pretty well, but I get a screen flash, like the `<route-loading>` component briefly loads and before the `<layout>` component gets it's data and is shown again.  I wonder if there is anyway to prevent the route change until the async data comes back and the `<layout>` just gets data updated and no unmount

Comment: I was able to get it working (I think) by moving the `<transition />` into `RouteHandler`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: AHHH I think this works!!  I swear I tried this but maybe not with the mode... Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool! Yeah, I just tried it on a clean Vue sample app (via jss create) and the code above seemed to trigger a distinct fade leave and fade enter transition when clicking on routes in the nav.